# sed: Replacing successful as the condition

Tags: sed, replace

I bumped into an excellent use of `sed` to do replacing, and use its successful state as the condition to print the line:

```bash
$ seq 3 | sed -n 's/2/B/ p'
B
```

I'm wondering if this short form can be extended to do more actions. Like,

- print the line only if the replacement is successful, but
- before printing out, I need to do more replacing

Would that be possible? I tried the following but failed:

```bash
$ seq 3 | sed -n 's/2/B/ {p}'
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown option to `s'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p` here is a flag to the `sed` command, it's not the `p` `sed` command.

To do something (other than `p`rinting the resulting pattern space or `w`riting it to a file, `w` being another one of the flags one may use with the `s` command) only if a substitution was made you can use the `t` command (or the `T` command in GNU `sed`) which branches to some label (or to the end if no label) if there was a substitution (if there wasn't for `-T`), so you can do:

GNU specific:

```
sed -n 's/2/B/;T;=;p;#and other commands if there were substitutions'
```

Which is like:

```
substitute(the first occurrence of 2 with B in the pattern space)
if (no substitution was made so far)
   goto(end)
print-pattern-space
print-input-line-number
: end
```

Standardly:

```
sed '
  s/2/B/;t more
  d
  :more
  p;=;#and other commands
'
```

Or you can use:

```
sed -n '/regexp/ { s//replacement/; p; =; }'
```

Where using an empty regexp reuses the previous one like in `ed`.

Comment: Thanks for answering precisely what I've been asking. `sed -n 's/2/B/;T;s/B/bb/;p;'` works marviously!!

Comment: Hmm, the second `t more` example I was able to understand, but how the `sed -n 's/2/B/;T;=;p;'` is working I'm still a bit at lost. So, in this case, if a substitution was made, `T` will branches to the end (because there is no label), which will skip the execution of `=;p;`, right? how come they both are executed then?

Comment: @xpt, they're only both executed if there was no match. See if the edit with some added pseudo-code makes it clearer.

Comment: Ah, `T` is the opposite of `t`. _"you can use the t command (or the T command in GNU sed) "_ this gave me the impression that `t` in GNU sed is `T`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `/2/` as the address for a more complex command:

```bash
sed -n '/2/ { s/2/B/; /BB/d; p; }'
```

This would, for any line containing at least one `2`, replace the first occurrence of `2` with `B` (in this case, this substitution could also be shortened into `s//B/` where the empty regular expression means "use the most recently matched expression") and then discard the line if it now contains the substring `BB`.  Then the line would be outputted (if it wasn't discarded).  Other lines would not be outputted at all, due to `-n`.

You could also use

```bash
sed -e '/2/!d' -e 'other commands'
```

This would delete all lines that do not contain `2` and then apply `other commands` on the remaining lines.

Using multiple expressions, each given using `-e`, is the standard way of applying a series of commands to an input stream with `sed`.  Most current `sed` implementations also understand separating expressions with `;`.  GNU `sed` does not have to see a `;` before an `}`.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can group commands with the "{ .... }". The general form is:

```
/<regexp>/ {
             cmd1
             cmd2
             ...
           }
```

"cmd" here is any regular sed-command, like "s/.../.../", but also "p", "q", etc.. Think of this as a "rule", applicable to all lines matching the regexp. You can also negate the rule by using an exclamation mark between the regexp and the opening brace. In this case the rule is applied to all lines *not* matching the regexp.

Here is an example that prints all comment-only lines from the start of a script until the first non-comment line:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*#/ !{
                          q
                        }'
```

All lines that start with a "#" match the rule and are therefore just printed (we haven't used the "-n" option to suppress that). The first line (actually all lines, but effectively only the first one is processed) not matching the regexp triggers the rule which simply exits sed.

But there is also another device which is even more powerful than using rules: you define so-called "labels". Symbolic places to which you branch with a GOTO-like command. This is how it works:

**1) unconditional branching**
sed scripts work like this: the first line of input is read, then all sed-commands are applied to it, one after the other (if the line is changed further commands are applie to this changed line) until the last command is reached. If the "-n" option is not used the result is printed to . Only then the next line of input is read and the process starts anew, until the last line of input is processed.

There is a way to change the order commands are applied to the current line:

> : [label]

This command does nothing on itself but it can be used by other commands to branch to this place. You maybe remember languages like BASIC and their "goto" command? This marks a label to which a subsequent "goto"-(like)-command can jump. The unconditional sed-command to branch to a previously defined label is

> b [label]

The "b" stands for "branch".  corresponds to what you defined with the ":" command. If you omit the label execution branches to the end of the script.

Here is an example: you get a program, but unfortunately the code indentation is done with tab characters instead of spaces and you want to change that. Obviously you want to change ony the tabs in front of any code, not tabs within the code as these might be needed. Alas, there is no device in regular expressions for this directly, so you have to implement it yourself. The algorithm is: as long as a line is of the form *whitespace, followed by a tab* change this first tab to 8 blanks, then repeat on the same line until no tab is in ffront of any text. Only then print the line. This loop-like structure is set up using a ":" and a "b" command. Note that i use \b (blank) and \t (tab) here to make the different kinds of whitespace readable. Replace them by real blanks/tabs characters when testing the script:

```
sed ':start
     /^\b*\t/ {
                s/^\(\b*\)\t/\1\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b/
                b start
              }'
```

**2) conditional branching**
Now, that you know how to set up labels and branch to them there is an even further twist: you can branch to such a label depending on an s/.../.../ command executed before being successful (that means: it has changed something) or not. The commands to do that are:

> t [label]

which branches to  if one of the s/../../-commands did a successful substitution since the last line was read OR since the last execution of a t or T command and

> T [label]

which is the negated counterpart to "t". It branches if *no* s-command was successful.

Here is a simple example how that works. It doesn't do anything particularly useful, but it shows the principle: the sed-script takes only the first line of any input. If the first character is one of "a", "b" or "c" it prints "YES", otherwise "NO".

```
sed -n 's/^[abc]/x/
        t yes
        b no
        :no
        s/^.*$/NO/p
        q
        :yes
        s/^.*$/YES/p
        q'
```

The control flow is simple: first a substitution is attempted where the first character is changed to an "x" if it is "a", "b" or "c". In case this is successful the branching command "t yes" will branch to the lael "yes", where the whole line is changed to "YES" and sed exits (the "q" command). If this substition is not successful the "t"-command is passed and the "b" command is executed, jumping to the "no" label.

Experiment with various input (`echo "..." | sed <script>` is good enough) to see how it works, then change the "t"-command to a "T" and sobserve the effect on the results.

Comment: Appreciate the comprehensive answer, thanks. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do anything other than `s/old/new/` then you'd be better off using awk than sed for some combination of clarity, robustness, portability, maintainability, etc.:

```
$ seq 3 | awk 'sub(/2/,"B")'
B

$ seq 3 | awk 'sub(/2/,"B") { sub(/B/,"foo"); print }'
foo
```

Comment: If you use awk, you should use Perl. And if you use Perl, you should use Python. And if you use Python ... . There is always another tool one could use to do the same and one could suggest. awk is "clear" for those who use it regularly, like sed is "clear" for those who use that regularly.

Comment: @bakunin awk is a mandatory POSIX tool so it's present on all Unix machines, unlike perl and python, and no-one is creating cartoons about awk legibility like we see at https://www.zoitz.com/archives/13. awk is clear for anyone who understand any algol-based language and reads the awk man page for 5 mins to understand it's implicit while-read-split input loop and condition-action structure. I've been using sed for 40+ years and couldn't tell you what the last script in your answer does without the lengthy explanation you provided, nor which sed variant(s) it'll work in.

Comment: First, *awk is a mandatory POSIX tool* - yes, and sed is so, too. The script I provided works with any standards-conforming sed-implementation. Second, the number of cartoons is hardly a measurement of usability. There are lots of cartoons about vi - does that make vi a bad editor? And third, all this is not to say awk is a bad language. But I am really, really fed up with the constant stream of *Q: How can I do ... in X? A: Don't use X, use Y*-threads.

Comment: You need to get over that because frequently "Don't use X, use Y" is the right answer. I'm one of the [top answerers of sed-tagged questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/topusers) and it's not because I keep throwing out sed scripts every time the OP asks for one, it's because I provide good solutions to the problem the OP has using appropriate tools.

Comment: If this would be correct, "Use Windows" (z/OS, ...) could be written under every thread here, no? Q: "How can I indent code in vi? A: Use emacs!" "How can I do it in emacs? Use nano/pico/foobar/...!" etc., ad nauseam. "Use another tool" in my experience quite often means "use what I am comfortable with, because i have no idea how to answer the question".